# Certain css background rules ignored

Tags: css

I have an odd situation where the rules computed for my element background don't match the ones specified in my stylesheet:

```
#first {
  background: url('//my_image1.jpg');
}
#second {
  background: url('//my_image2.jpg');
}
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #fff;
}

<body>
<div id="first" class="container">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="second" class="container">Lorem ipsum</div>
</body>
```

Here's a working example to illustrate what I mean:
https://jsfiddle.net/4u96pLp5/

When I look at the computed rules, I see `background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 0 0` etc. Why are the `.container` background rules ignored in this case?

Comment: The url might be wrong, can you tell me your website address?

Comment: Is this what you expect? https://jsfiddle.net/4u96pLp5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `background` shorthand property within the `id` selector which has more specificity than the class selector. When the `shorthand` is used, the UA would set default value for all properties and then overwrite it with the provided value. Below is the extract from the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background):

> Given a valid declaration, for each layer the shorthand first sets the corresponding layer of each of ‘background-image’, ‘background-position’, ‘background-size’, ‘background-repeat’, ‘background-origin’, ‘background-clip’ and ‘background-attachment’ to that property's initial value, then assigns any explicit values specified for this layer in the declaration. Finally ‘background-color’ is set to the specified color, if any, else set to its initial value.

You should instead use the specific `background-image` property within the `id` selectors.

```css
#first {
  background-image: url('http://b03.deliver.odai.yale.edu/8a/47/8a4792dd-7691-4cdc-9266-8b4503b66e8b/ag-obj-28123-001-pub-sm.jpg');
}
#second {
  background-image: url('http://c8.staticflickr.com/8/7460/27208472271_63bf023f2f_k.jpg');
}
#third {
  background-image: url('http://b01.deliver.odai.yale.edu/a4/29/a429173e-b15f-41fe-bf70-32f8d765f541/ag-obj-52875-001-pub-sm.jpg');
}
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div id="second" class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
  anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div id="third" class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`background` sets all the background properties, overriding, because of specificity, the background-* settings from `.container` . Use `background-image` instead.